# How to change the text property on sweet alerts in angular?

Tags: angular, sweetalert, sweetalert2

Below is my function & i am getting value as parameter.

Based on the value I need to show custom text in. Below is my code.

```
buttonClicked(value) {
    console.log(value);
    swal({
      title: 'Are you sure?',
      text: 'ssss',
      type: 'warning',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',
      confirmButtonText: 'Delete',
      // closeOnConfirm: true
    }).then((result) => {
      if (result === true) {
      }
    }, function (dismiss) { });
  }
```

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using sweetalert2 then there are some issues with your code. The cancel button action of the sweetalert is not working as expected you need to modify it like below. Also you can store the value of the custom text in a variable depending on the value passed from the function like below

```js
function buttonClicked(value){
    console.log(value);
    var customText;
    if(value =='First button'){
      customText = "first button clicked";
    }
    else if(value =='Second button'){
     customText = "second button clicked";
    }
    
    swal({
      title: 'Are you sure?',
      text: customText,
      type: 'warning',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',
      confirmButtonText: 'Delete',
    }).then((result) => {
      if (result.value) {
       alert("Deleted");
      }
    else if(result.dismiss == swal.DismissReason.cancel) { 
      alert('cancel');
    }
  });
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@7.24.1/dist/sweetalert2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@7.24.1/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="buttonClicked('First button')">
First button
</button> <br>

<button onclick="buttonClicked('Second button')">
Second button
</button>
```

Here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zvseqond/1/